# Basic SQL Question - Query two Data Extensions for Overlap

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I need to query two data extensions to find any overlap between them. Our subscriber key for both DEs is Salesforce ID. Is there a simple query to use to compare these to see if any subscribers exist in both DEs?

Comment: You should consider an Inner join between the 2 tables, the result will give you records that exist in both data extensions. Please try writing a query and post the query along with the error if you would like additional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, b.field1
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: you might want to add an explanation to your code dump for the OP to undestand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this query ago it’s a good starting point. Go and enjoy yourself

SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON b.salesforceid = a.salesforceid